# How do I keep a counter of a nested loop?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have a 2D array that I need to traverse through, where each inner looping adds a new View. I've tried having a @State variable and increasing it by one on onAppear, like in this simplified example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { i in
            ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { j in
                Text("Iteration #\(counter)")
                    .onAppear {
                        counter += 1
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me nine TextViews with the text "Iteration #8". How can I make it show each value from 0 to 8 like a counter would?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question. I do see one issue with the code though. In its current state it will not run. You will need to add a State property wrapper before your counter variable - i.e. @State private var counter = -1. If this is what you are looking for, I can type up a more comprehensive answer as to why this is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I reworded my question; hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Updated question is much clearer! If you are looking for the current iteration (in either loop), you can just plug in the variable you use within each loop (i.e. Text("Iteration #\(j)") or Text("Iteration #\(i)") ) -- does this lead to your desired result?

Comment: Not quite. I want to display the running total of the number of Text views displayed, AKA the running total of the numbers of times the inner loop runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForEach is really just for constructing views that require repeated use of the same models. In this case, I separated out the incrementing logic into a function. You can then use the result of this function to construct a view that creates as many text fields as desired. Note that the ForEach is counting up to the return value of our iterateCounter function.

This may not be the exact math you need, but you can modify the numbers to make it work for you!

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = -1
    
    var count: Int {
        iterateCounter()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0...count, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("Iteration #\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func iterateCounter() -> Int {
        var count1 = 0
        var count2 = 0
        
        for _ in 0...2 {
            count1 += 1
            for _ in 0...2 {
                count2 += 2
            }
        }
        return count1 + count2
    }
}
```